# An expression in a function is not evaluating to true when it should. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript

I am making a function to wait until a condition is true, then execute a function. The expression inputted is a == 5. a starts equal to 0, and every time the function is executed it goes up by 1. when it is equal to five, the function still evaluates to false.

my .js file:

```
var _ = {
    waitUntil: function(duringExecution, expression, onCompletion) {
        test();
        function test(){
            console.log(a + ' ' + expression);
            if((expression) == true) {
                onCompletion();
            } else {
                duringExecution();
                setTimeout(test, 200);
            }
        }
    }
}

a = 0;
_.waitUntil(function() {
    a++;
}, a == 5, function() {
    console.log('yay');
});
```

My HTML file has nothing in it, except for the script tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example lul</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src='under.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Every time the function is run, it prints the value of a and the results of the expression. The console just prints:

```
1 false
2 false
3 false
4 false
5 false
6 false
7 false
...
```

It just goes forever. When a == 5, it should print `a true` and stop, but it doesn't.

Comment: Because `a == 5` evaluates to `false` (`a` is 0 when you pass it)

Comment: ohhhhhh... do you have any suggestions for what to do next?

Comment: Use a function, I posted an answer with a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you write an expression its always evaluated to its value. For example when you pass `a == 5` to function it return `false` and `false` is passed to the function.

You need to wrap `a == 5` in a function. And call it when you want to check the condition.

```js
var _ = {
    waitUntil: function(duringExecution, expression, onCompletion) {
        test();
        function test(){
            console.log(a + ' ' + expression());
            if(expression() == true) {
                onCompletion();
            } else {
                duringExecution();
                setTimeout(test, 500);
            }
        }
    }
}

a = 0;
_.waitUntil(function() {
    a++;
},function(){ 
    return a == 5
}, function() {
    console.log('yay');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem, but it would be nice if you didn't have to. Is there any way to have _.waitUntil turn a == 5 into a function or not? (I don't know what I'm really talking about so please let me know if i'm wrong.)

Comment: @MarkC.That is strange. for me it seems to work fine.

Comment: @MarkC. Sorry Its fixed now. I was missing `return`

Comment: @DanielReynolds You will need to wrap `a == 5` in a function. If you want to pass `a == 5` only and change it to function dynamically inside `_.waitUntil` then its not possible.

Comment: @MarkC. ok. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielReynolds You can do what by passing a string `"a == 5"` and convert it to a function using `new Function` but I won't suggest you to use `new Function`. Also you can use arrow functions to shorten your code.

Answer (score 2):

`==` is a comparison operator, it either evaluates to `true` or `false`, depending on the operands, you can't use it as an "expresion" you can evaluate later. You need to use a function instead.

```js
var _ = {
    waitUntil: function(duringExecution, expression, onCompletion) {
        test();
        function test(){
            console.log(a + ' ' + expression());
            if(expression() == true) {
                onCompletion();
            } else {
                duringExecution();
                setTimeout(test, 200);
            }
        }
    }
}

function compareA() {
  return a == 5;
}

a = 0;
_.waitUntil(function() {
    a++;
}, compareA, function() {
    console.log('yay');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute this:

```
_.waitUntil(function() {
    a++;
}, a == 5, function() {
    console.log('yay');
});
```

`a == 5` is evaluated as `false` right away, so your `waitUntil` function is receiving the following inputs:

- `duringExecution` = `function () { a++ }`
- `expression` = `false`
- `onCompletion` = `function () { console.log('yay') }`

What you need is to make the second argument a function that returns whether or not `a` is `5`, and change your `waitUntil` function to call it on every iteration. So, your function definition would be:

```js
var _ = {
    waitUntil: function(duringExecution, expression, onCompletion) {
        test();
        function test(){
            console.log(a + ' ' + expression);
            if (expression()) { // <-- changed this line to call `expression`, removed `== true` as it's not necessary, "if" is already checking for a truthy value
                onCompletion();
            } else {
                duringExecution();
                setTimeout(test, 200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your call would be:

```js
_.waitUntil(function() {
    a++;
}, function () {
  return a == 5;
}, function() {
    console.log('yay');
});
```

Or, a shorter version using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
_.waitUntil(
  () => { a++ },
  () => a == 5,
  () => console.log('yay')
);
```